# Will boost::condition improve the performance?

Tags: c++, multithreading, boost, boost-thread

We have a multiple threads application. In current implementation, **thread1** is created at start up and periodically (every second or so, configurable) wakes up to check the disk for potential saved files. These files are saved by another thread, **thread2**. That running **thread1** and its periodically wake up may slow down the application.

Now we have a chance to use boost::condition variable to put **thread1** blocked until **thread2** notifies it. By doing so, a flag needs to be created to avoid unnecessary notify from **thread2** and that flag needs to be synchronized and be checked with  high frequency (hundreds in few seconds) by **thread2**. Or **thread1** will be notified each time when writing happens.

My questions here are the following:

1. In the boost::condition implementation, the **thread1** still needs to wake up frequently to check a flag and the difference is the implementation is hidden from us but it actually does that. Am I right? Similar API in Windows and Java do the same thing?
2. What will happen if a thread is notified frequently many times even it is not in waiting state?
3. In my case, it will improve the overall performance by switching to  boost::condition implementation? My opinion is No.

Comment: It depends on how boost::condition is implemented. If it uses system condition variables, thread1 should be withdrawn from scheduling until notified, incurring no awakening until notified.

Comment: The flag, you mention, is to be set when a new file is created and reset when thread1 finishes with this file?

Comment: yes. thread2 set that flag to let thread1 knows file is ready. thread1 will process it and then reset that flag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. In POSIX and Win32 boost::condition is implemented using event based APIs. Technically thread doesn't wake up until it gets an event.
2. If thread goes into wait after the signal has been sent - the signal would be lost. You should read about event based patterns and strategies for implementing "producer/consumer". Your file write/read example is classic producer/consumer instance. In order to avoid lost signal please implement it similar to the C++11 example in Wikipedia: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Producer%E2%80%93consumer_problem#Example_in_C.2B.2B

The idea is that thread1 will always lock shared mutex if it doesn't wait for condition:

```
//thread1 - consumer
void thread1() {
    boost::scoped_lock lock(sharedMutex);
    // shared mutex locked, no events can be sent now
    while(1) {
        // check for files written by thread2
        sharedCond.wait( lock ); // this action unlocks the shared mutex, events can be sent now
    }
}

//thread2 - producer
void thread2() {
    boost::scoped_lock lock(sharedMutex); // will wait here until thread 1 starts waiting
    // write files
    sharedCond.notify_one();
}
```

3. Performance question: this change is not about the performance, but changing the polling to event model. If your thread1 was awake every 1 second, switching to event model won't improve CPU or I/O load (eliminate file verification every 1 second), until you run in embedded system where frequency is few KHz and I/O operation blocks the entire process.
It will improve thread1 reaction time, in polling mode the max response time to file change would be 1 second, and after switching to event it would be immediate action.
On the other hand thread2 performance might degrade in event model - before it didn't wait for anything, and if it uses condition - it will have to lock the shared mutex, that might be locked all time thread1 is reading the files.

Answer (score 0):

Checking a flag with high frequency is exactly what boost::condition allows you to avoid. `thread1()` just waits for the `flag` to be set:

```
#include <mutex>
#include <condition_variable>
#include <thread>

std::mutex mut;
bool flag;
std::condition_variable data_cond;

void thread2()
{
    //here, writing to a file
    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lk(mut);
    flag = true;  //a new file is saved
    data_cond.notify_one();
}

void thread1()
{
    while(true)
    {
        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lk(mut);
        data_cond.wait(lk,[]{return flag;});
        //here, processing the file
        flag = false;
        lk.unlock();
    }
}
```

This is a C++11 code based on Listing 4_1 in: [*C++ Concurrency in Action*, Chapter 4 Synchronizing concurrent operations](http://www.manning.com/williams/)